# Baffling issue with CoreData: setAttribute has no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have this object (removed unrelated attributes):

```
HFAppointment; id: 0xd8ec6f0 <x-coredata://2AA46AB1-11AF-431B-9289-63DEFCDAFED6/HFAppointment/p2> ; data: {
    cost = 60;
    deleted = 0;
})
```

Along with this simple bit of code:

```
[appointment setDeleted:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[appointment setCost:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

The problem is that after running this code I get:

```
HFAppointment; id: 0xd8ec6f0 <x-coredata://2AA46AB1-11AF-431B-9289-63DEFCDAFED6/HFAppointment/p2> ; data: {
    cost = 1;
    deleted = 0;
})
```

The `NSManagedObject` subclass looks like this:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface HFAppointment : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cost;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * deleted;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "HFAppointment.h"

@implementation HFAppointment

@dynamic cost;
@dynamic deleted;

@end
```

And that's it, I have no custom setters or getters for that class. I searched the whole project for occurences of `deleted` and it's only used in predicates, there's no other class using that setter.

I have tried deleting and recreating the `NSManagedObject` subclass with no success. I also tried deleting the app from the simulator and did a clean build to no avail.

For the record, the `deleted` attribute looks like this (changing to Integer 32 and/or removing the default value and/or using `int32_t` instead of `NSNumber` has no effect):

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After endlessly searching for countless hours, turns out the solution was simple, although obscure.

[This article](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/192347-core-data-reserved-property-names.html) led me to find out that `deleted` is apparently a reserved keyword in CoreData. Simply renaming the attribute fixed the problem. I can't find a list of those keywords to back up my answer so if someone is aware of such a list, please feel free to post it.

The [NSPropertyDescription documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html) does sort of mention `optional`, `transient` and `readOnly`, but that's all I could find and it's less than clear that they must not be used.

The deeply annoying part is that XCode never issued any sort of warning related to this so it really was guess work.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with an attribute called 'updated'